# Access a record, after filtering a list of type sum

Tags: opa

I have a list of

```
type my_sum = {a : type_a} / {b : type_b}
mylist = [{field_only_in_a = "test"} : type_a,{haha=3 ; fsd=4} : type_b]
```

I want to do that :

```
result = List.find( a -> match a with 
                                      | {a = _} -> true
                                      | _ -> false
                                     end,
                                mylist)
 if Option.is_some(result) then
     Option.some(Option.get(result).field_only_in_a)
 else
     Option.none
```

Like you can see, after the find I'm sure to get something of `type_a` but on compilation time I get that :

```
    Record has type
{ a : type_a } / { b : type_b }  but field access expected it to have type
{ field_only_in_a: 'a; 'r.a }
Hint:
  You tried to access a sum type with several cases as a record.
```

How could I say to the compilator, that I have extract only one type of the sum type and that I have the good type to acces the record... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you cannot really inform the compiler that only a subtype will exist in the list... but you can explicitly create a list with this subtype only. Actually, what you are looking for is `List.find_map` which find a first element matching a certain criteria and maps it (you use this mapping to project from `my_sum` to its case `type_a`). Below is a fully working code (compiles on its own):

```
type type_a = {fld_a : string}
type type_b = {fld_b : int}
type my_sum = {a : type_a} / {b : type_b}

mylist = [{a = {fld_a = "test"}}, {b = {fld_b = 10}}] : list(my_sum)

get_first_a(l : list(my_sum)) : option(type_a) =
  List.find_map(
    (el -> match el
           | ~{a} -> some(a)
           | _ -> none
    ), l)

_ = prerr("First a-typed element of {mylist} is {get_first_a(mylist)}\n")
```

If there was no `List.find_map` function in the stdlib there would still be a ton of ways to do it. Probably the simplest would be to use `List.filter_map` to obtain a `list(type_a)` and then get its head with `List.head_opt`.